# Remove comma from sub string

Tags: ruby

I have to eliminate comma from a substring of a string using gsub . Here is the example sting.

```
"2015-12-01,20615715,93801,\"Digital Throttle,LLC\",176333,Hemmings Motor News,300x600,180"
```

So the expected output should be

```
"2015-12-01,20615715,93801,\"Digital Throttle LLC\",176333,Hemmings Motor News,300x600,180"
```

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @sawa : there is difference in `Digital Throttle,LLC`(example) and `Digital Throttle LLC` (expected)

Comment: @sawa It should remove commas in quoted strings.

Comment: Provide reason before downvote

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain why the comma in "Throttle,LLC" should be replaced with a space, but the other commas should not?

Comment: @WayneConrad I have to apply split method on that string ("".split(','))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` for your example.

```
x.gsub(/(\".*?),(.*?\")/, '\1 \2')
```

For more than one comma between the quotes you can repeat this call until the values doesn't change anymore.

Comment: You do not need to repeat this call. `gsub` does this implicitly. That's what the `g` stands for.

Comment: @pramod: The solution proposed by sschmeck returns the modified copy of the string. If you want to change the variable `x` itself, use `gsub!` instead of `gsub`.

Comment: @user1934428 There is a problem when the additional comma is part of the captures. Therefore you have to repeat.

Comment: You are right .... this would occur, if we have more than one comma in a quoted string. In this case, I would write it like this: `x.gsub(/(\".*?),(.*?\")/) { |m| m.gsub(/,/,'') }`. This would capture the quoted parts, and then have undergo each one a second substitution.